# Semantic Web - Store app data directly in RDF or store in SQL and export/import later

Tags: sql-server, windows, oracle, iis, rdf

I have a standard IIS web application which stores its data in a standard SQL Server or Oracle DB.
I'm now interested in storing the data in [RDF](http://www.rdfabout.com/quickintro.xpd) format, to go full **Semantic Web**.

Is it recommended to store data directly in RDF format? CRUDQ operations will be done on the data. Performance wise is this a good move?

**If not** (like I'm assuming), I guess I'd maintain standard SQL DBs and export/import data to/from RDF? How can I do this? Are there good converters out there?

Answer (score 6):

If you really want to stick with a relational database, which I don't recommend, you can use something like [D2RQ](http://d2rq.org/) or you can look for something that supports, say, [R2RML](http://www.w3.org/TR/r2rml/).  Or you could try [SDB](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/sdb/index.html).

However, if you want to use semantic technologies, you are much better off using an actual RDF database.  You'll get better performance and you'll have a better development experience.  There are a lot of options out there, [Mulgara](http://mulgara.org), [Jena](http://jena.apache.org), [Sesame](http://openrdf.org), [Stardog](http://stardog.com), [OWLIM](http://www.ontotext.com/owlim), [AllegroGraph](http://www.franz.com/agraph/allegrograph/), [BigData](http://www.systap.com/bigdata.htm), [Virtuoso](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/rdf-quad-store/), and Oracle provides some RDF support if you have an Oracle license, but in my experience, it's not as performant as dedicated RDF databases.

A lot of the SemWeb toolchain is in Java, but since you mentioned IIS, perhaps you're in the MS world, in which case, [dotNetRDF](http://www.dotnetrdf.org/) is a good option.

But in summary, use dedicated RDF/SemWeb tools if you're going to be using the technology.  Don't try and shoehorn RDF into non-semantic stuff, and don't write your own.  No need to re-invent the wheel, there's lots of good SemWeb software out there to get your project going.

Answer (score 2):

I think the point is what interface you will use/implement on your (?) data.

There are several way to go, my own would use SWI-Prolog to model the RDF storage, possibly with [SPARQL](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%282,%279%27,swi%28%27/doc/packages/semweb.html%27%29%29), while accessing raw data via [ODBC](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%282,%272%27,swi%28%27/doc/packages/odbc.html%27%29%29).

Then i have a chance to avoid static mapping (converting can be a risk, i think) at least until some 'stable' semantic emerges from data.

SWI-Prolog has also some point as reporting tool, and generative Web presentation.

Writing in Prolog [the W3C rules to map](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-rdb-direct-mapping-20110324/) 'automatically' relations to triples seems an interesting task, I'll try it...